# Generate time array for shifts ending at or after midnight

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, unnest

I am trying to generate each hour (`time`) between `start_of_shift` and `end_of_shift` (hours of the start and end of the shift should be included too).
The query below works fine as long as an employee doesn't have a shift ending at or over midnight.

```
SELECT 
      employee_id,
      shift_id,
      date_of_shift, --date
      TIME(hour,0,0) AS time,
      start_of_shift, --datetime
      end_of_shift,  --datetime
    FROM shift_table ,UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 23)) AS hour
    WHERE hour BETWEEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_of_shift) AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_of_shift) AND 
      date_of_shift = "2023-05-04" 
      AND employee_id = 111111
    ORDER BY 2,3
```

Is there a way to use `UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 23))`to obtain the expected outcome (show shifts ending at or after midnight)? Or what would be the best approach if not possible?

Current results:

| employee_id | shift_id | date_of_shift | time | start_of_shift | end_of_shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 1234 | 2023-05-04 | 15:00:00 | 15:05:00 | 17:22:00 |
| 111111 | 1234 | 2023-05-04 | 16:00:00 | 15:05:00 | 17:22:00 |
| 111111 | 1234 | 2023-05-04 | 17:00:00 | 15:05:00 | 17:22:00 |

Expected results:

| employee_id | shift_id | date_of_shift | time | start_of_shift | end_of_shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 1234 | 2023-05-04 | 15:00:00 | 15:05:00 | 17:22:00 |
| 111111 | 1234 | 2023-05-04 | 16:00:00 | 15:05:00 | 17:22:00 |
| 111111 | 1234 | 2023-05-04 | 17:00:00 | 15:05:00 | 17:22:00 |
| 111111 | 2345 | 2023-05-04 | 22:00:00 | 22:00:00 | 01:09:00 |
| 111111 | 2345 | 2023-05-04 | 23:00:00 | 22:00:00 | 01:09:00 |
| 111111 | 2345 | 2023-05-04 | 00:00:00 | 22:00:00 | 01:09:00 |
| 111111 | 2345 | 2023-05-04 | 01:00:00 | 22:00:00 | 01:09:00 |

Note: Changing the date range doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

There is function `generate_timestamp_array` which can creates an array of all times with a given time step between two timestamp.

```
select generate_timestamp_array(timestamp_trunc(timestamp(start_shift),hour), timestamp(end_shift), INTERVAL 1 hour)
from (select datetime "2023-03-03 22:05:00" as start_shift, datetime "2023-03-04 01:05:00" as end_shift )
```